# Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятые в пропущенные места в скобках?:

"...с добрыми() зелеными() немного раскосыми глазами."

"Даже такой самоуверенный мужчина() как Виктор() может в чем-то сомневаться."

"Причем() где-то он его уже видел."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...с добрыми зелеными, немного раскосыми глазами.

Даже такой самоуверенный мужчина, как Виктор, может в чем-то сомневаться (http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_722).

Причем где-то он его уже видел (http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_641).